# por que no puedo ver etiquetas html ingresado en un varchar en mi base de datos mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

alguien me podría ayudar o dar a conocer el como puedo ver las etiquetas que guardo en una base de datos es decir:
1.tengo una tabla de respuestas , en la columna de **contenido_res**     vemos como hay un texto guardado con una etiqueta de imagen    
[image: imagen de tabla]

2.visualizo esa tabla, y vemos como se carga la imagen del tomate 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.al momento de editarlo **desaparece mágicamente la etiqueta de img**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

anexo codigo de editar

```html
 <!--Modal para CRUD-->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="modalCRUD" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form id="formTitulos">    
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">respuesta:</label>
                          <textarea  type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="contenido_res" placeholder="Escribe una respuesta"  rows="15" cols="20" name="contenido_res" required></textarea>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-dark">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

con este codigo edito en el js

```js
//Editar        
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function() {
  opcion = 2; //editar
  fila = $(this).closest("tr");
  id_respuestas = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text()); //capturo el ID                   
  contenido_res = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();


  $("#contenido_res").val(contenido_res);


  $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#198754");
  $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
  $(".modal-title").text("Editar Respuesta");
  $('#modalCRUD').modal('show');
});
```

¿hay alguna forma de que cargue también la etiqueta al momento de editar la respuesta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir el contenido en html en lugar de texto puro puedes usar el método [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) de jquery, por lo tanto debes modificar esta línea:

```javascript
contenido_res = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

por esta otra:

```javascript
contenido_res = fila.find('td:eq(1)').html();
```

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function() {
  opcion = 2; //editar
  fila = $(this).closest("tr");
  id_respuestas = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text()); //capturo el ID                   
  contenido_res = fila.find('td:eq(1)').html();


  $("#contenido_res").val(contenido_res);


  $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#198754");
  $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
  $(".modal-title").text("Editar Respuesta");
  $('#modalCRUD').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
<tr><td></td><td>Texto puro <img src="lalala"></td><td><button class="btnEditar">
Editar
</button></td></tr>

</table>


<!--Modal para CRUD-->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="modalCRUD" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form id="formTitulos">    
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">respuesta:</label>
                          <textarea  type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="contenido_res" placeholder="Escribe una respuesta"  rows="15" cols="20" name="contenido_res" required></textarea>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-dark">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: te agradezco mucho @masterguru con ese pequeño cambio obtuve el resultado que quería